# SQLite with mvvmcross

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an SQLite database set up within my mvvmcross android application like this

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    object dbLock = new object();
    readonly ISQLiteConnection connection;

    public DataService(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        connection = factory.Create("mydatabase.db3; New=true; Version=3;PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE; PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL; PRAGMA cache_size=20000; PRAGMA page_size=32768; PRAGMA synchronous=off");
    }
```

within my HomeviewViewModel, the database is set up and the tables inserted. There are no issues there.

When I come to insert into the database, any calls to connection.Execute results in the app crashing with an error to say that you can't execute on an unopened database.

The insert/update looks like this

```
    public void AddOrUpdateContacts(List<Connections> contacts)
    {
        foreach (var sr in contacts)
            AddOrUpdateContacts(sr);
    }

    public void AddOrUpdateContacts(Connections contact)
    {
        lock (dbLock)
        {
            using (var sqlcon = connection)
            {
                sqlcon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
                sqlcon.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    if (sqlcon.Execute("UPDATE StoreItem SET Id=?, " +
                            "Name=?, Phone=?, InviteSent=?, InviteAccepted=?, CanShareWith=?, TypeOfContact=? WHERE Id=?",
                            contact.Id, contact.Name, contact.Phone, contact.InviteSent, contact.InviteAccepted, contact.CanShareWith, contact.TypeOfContact, contact.Id) == 0)
                        sqlcon.Insert(contact, typeof(Connections));
                    sqlcon.Commit(); 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    #if DEBUG
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in AddOrUpdateContacts - {0}--{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                    #endif
                    sqlcon.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've used this code in non-PCL and Xamarin.Forms apps without a hitch. When I check connection prior to the Execute call, it is correctly set.

Comment: Does this crash second time? The `using (var sqlcon = connection)` makes me suspicious that you dispose (close) the connection after each execution.

Comment: It happily creates the table but but dies as soon as the first execute is hit. The close each time should be fine (as I say, I've used this code many times in both non pcl and Xamarin forms apps).

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. if you Dispose it, how can you then use it? (Maybe this is just because I can only see part of the code)

Comment: The only thing disposed is the copy of the connection object, not the object itself. As I say, if I run the debugger on it with a break point on the Execute, connection still contains the object. As soon as I hit the execute, boom, app crashes

Comment: I'm lost... how are you getting "the copy of the connection object"?

Comment: connection is set up at the start. When I enter the method, I make a copy of the connection in the var sqlcon and then only use that. What looks to be happening though is that the database is open on the first time through but then closing and not reopening, so the copy is reflecting back into the readonly connection and changing if from open to closed.

Comment: That's a reference - not a copy. As far as I can see, if that code worked in any other platform, it was only if `Dispose` did nothing in those platforms...

Comment: Hmm, I know it works fine in monodroid and mono touch without any issues. Odd,

Comment: Over and out on this from me on this one. `Dispose` is working correctly above IMHO. BTW... If you want to improve performance, then try grouping your Inserts together inside one Transaction.

Comment: `var sqlcon = connection` calls `Dispose()` on the reference to `connection`, which means you should get some kind of exception when you try to use it again. If you want to copy something you need to use a `Copy` method or implement `ICloneable`